# web server redundancy in case of network failure

Tags: networking, backup, failover, web, redundancy

I have a (web) server at a datacenter, which at times (as all datacenters do) has network failures (for like 10-30 minutes).

I have a second server at a different company (datacenter) which I could use as a failover solution.

Now, I was wondering how I could do that? Of course I can mirror the site. The problem is, how do I achieve this: When the main server let's say IP: 1.2.3.4 at datacenter A is not reachable from the outside world, how does my second server at IP: 4.3.2.1 automatically resume its work as main server ?

I don't think that round robin dns would be a solution, because half the requests will be directed to the server which is not reachable.

my servers are windows, IIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place the load balancer off site. Colocate a redundant hardware loadbalancer in a high-uptime third datacenter(costly but v.nice) or use a cloud service to deploy a redundant software load balancer(way cheaper). If you really can't get the budget, go dns.

Comment: Are you saying he needs a third server?

Comment: Well, at least two load balancer units in some form of cluster configuration (operating as one unit) for redundant load distribution/failover. Or a resilient cloud service.

Answer (score 3):

You are right - round robin DNS would not be a solution in this case. What you need is a DNS service that monitors the availability of your servers and switches over the DNS record for the web site to a failover IP once a problem occurs.

An example of such a service is [DNS Made Easy's DNS failover service](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/dns-failover-system-monitoring/).

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there any FASTER solution? the delay with this seems to be 2-4 min ping time + TTL of dns record which means on average 5-8 minutes. Isn't there any way for "instant" switch over?

Comment: If you plan to use only the two servers, then no. There are services like CloudFlare (https://www.cloudflare.com/overview) that provide cached content when your site goes down. You could also use a proxy server or a load balancer in front of your servers, but that's not very optimal when the servers are in different datacenters, and it adds just one more point of failure.

Comment: yeah that's my point, a proxy or a load balancer would still be in one of the datacenters that can fail, so if the datacenter network goes down, so does the loadbalancer/proxy. I will check out this dns mady easy's solution. thank you.

Comment: Also, as a side note, if your hosting provider experiences frequent downtime of 10-30 minutes, I would consider looking for another provider, or even AWS or some other cloud provider.